# Cannot resolve method 'addOnCompleteListener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have some problem with FireBase in Android Studio. Here is code:

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString())
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                Intent i = new Intent(SigningActivity.this, CreateComicActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("user", user);
                startActivity(i);
            } else {
                FirebaseUser user = null;
                Toast.makeText(SigningActivity.this, "Регистрация неуспешна. Попробуйте ещё раз", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

My error:

> Cannot resolve method 'addOnCompleteListener(anonymous android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener, anonymous com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener<com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult>)'

My dependies:

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
}
```

Comment: How is "mAuth" object defined?